# Uploading audio to facebook from iOS app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, soundcloud

I've been trying to integrate my app with Soundcloud, but I'm just finding that impossible and way too difficult, and there are no good tutorials out there. Are there any other ways to upload audio files to facebook for playback? Any other services besides Soundcloud? Or does anyone know a useful tutorial for setting up Soundcloud with iOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is kind of cheating, but you could upload your "audio" to youtube, and then use the facebook api to post the link (pretty easy using [facebook api](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/)).  Uploading to youtube would have better support, like [this](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/)

The soundcloud instructions [here](https://github.com/soundcloud/cocoa-api-wrapper/blob/master/Sharing.md) aren't terrible, a little tricky at first. Perhaps you could share with us what you've done on these three requirements. Where are you getting stuck?

1)Getting the users connections
2)Provide UI for choosing connections (public sharing) or mail addresses (private sharing)
3)Upload the file

EDIT
Additionaly, here is a useful tutorial [link](http://developers.soundcloud.com/blog/ios-sharing) for soundcloud uploading

Comment: Well for one the first API tutorial is causing me a lot of problems. I don't use git, so I just downloaded the project, but it doesn't include OAuth like they said it did. I get a lot of missing files error

Answer (score 4):

you can use their api to do what you want. first upload the audio file to soundcloud and then post the link to the file on facebook.

here is a link to [iOS sharing](http://developers.soundcloud.com/blog/ios-sharing) and here is a link to the [soundcloud api wrapper](https://github.com/soundcloud/cocoa-api-wrapper).
iOS sharing will help you post the link to Facebook.

Comment: I'm looking for a tutorial..it's a little advanced

Answer (score 0):

Both SoundCloud and Facebook have Cocoa wrappers and tutorial for their APIs:

[SoundCloud Cocoa API Wrapper + tuts](https://github.com/soundcloud/cocoa-api-wrapper/)

[Facebook iOS Tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/)

Hope these help.